# How to understand System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement.PrincipalContext Source code

Tags: c#, .net

I am curious about how does `System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement.PrincipalContext` work

Its source code as below

```
public partial class PrincipalContext : System.IDisposable
{
    public PrincipalContext(System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement.ContextType contextType) { throw new System.PlatformNotSupportedException(System.SR.DirectoryServicesAccountManagement_PlatformNotSupported);  }
    public PrincipalContext(System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement.ContextType contextType, string name) { throw new System.PlatformNotSupportedException(System.SR.DirectoryServicesAccountManagement_PlatformNotSupported);  }
    public PrincipalContext(System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement.ContextType contextType, string name, string container) { throw new System.PlatformNotSupportedException(System.SR.DirectoryServicesAccountManagement_PlatformNotSupported);  }
    public PrincipalContext(System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement.ContextType contextType, string name, string container, System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement.ContextOptions options) { throw new System.PlatformNotSupportedException(System.SR.DirectoryServicesAccountManagement_PlatformNotSupported);  }
    public PrincipalContext(System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement.ContextType contextType, string name, string container, System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement.ContextOptions options, string userName, string password) { throw new System.PlatformNotSupportedException(System.SR.DirectoryServicesAccountManagement_PlatformNotSupported);  }
    public PrincipalContext(System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement.ContextType contextType, string name, string userName, string password) { throw new System.PlatformNotSupportedException(System.SR.DirectoryServicesAccountManagement_PlatformNotSupported);  }
    public PrincipalContext(System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement.ContextType contextType, string name, string container, string userName, string password) { throw new System.PlatformNotSupportedException(System.SR.DirectoryServicesAccountManagement_PlatformNotSupported);  }
    public string ConnectedServer { get { throw new System.PlatformNotSupportedException(System.SR.DirectoryServicesAccountManagement_PlatformNotSupported);  } }
    public string Container { get { throw new System.PlatformNotSupportedException(System.SR.DirectoryServicesAccountManagement_PlatformNotSupported);  } }
    public System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement.ContextType ContextType { get { throw new System.PlatformNotSupportedException(System.SR.DirectoryServicesAccountManagement_PlatformNotSupported);  } }
    public string Name { get { throw new System.PlatformNotSupportedException(System.SR.DirectoryServicesAccountManagement_PlatformNotSupported);  } }
    public System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement.ContextOptions Options { get { throw new System.PlatformNotSupportedException(System.SR.DirectoryServicesAccountManagement_PlatformNotSupported);  } }
    public string UserName { get { throw new System.PlatformNotSupportedException(System.SR.DirectoryServicesAccountManagement_PlatformNotSupported);  } }
    public void Dispose() { }
    public bool ValidateCredentials(string userName, string password) { throw new System.PlatformNotSupportedException(System.SR.DirectoryServicesAccountManagement_PlatformNotSupported);  }
    public bool ValidateCredentials(string userName, string password, System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement.ContextOptions options) { throw new System.PlatformNotSupportedException(System.SR.DirectoryServicesAccountManagement_PlatformNotSupported);  }
}
```

You can see, just put throw new exception for implementation.

If you pick up one error msg, like `System.SR.DirectoryServicesAccountManagement_PlatformNotSupported`, this make me more confused, source code as below

```
internal static string @DirectoryServicesAccountManagement_PlatformNotSupported => GetResourceString("DirectoryServicesAccountManagement_PlatformNotSupported");
```

Here are my questions:

1. Where is the other half `PrincipalContext`?
2. How does this class work with just throwing Exception?
3. What will I get if I call `GetResourceString("DirectoryServicesAccountManagement_PlatformNotSupported")`?
4. Is the `System.SR` well-designed?

Thank you.